# PercentRelativeLayout is deprecated in v26

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

I want to display a layout with 6 views which I am setting by width and height percentage.
But `PercentageLayout` is deprecated in Android v26
What is the alternative for `PercentageLayout`. Android documentation is saying to use `ConstraintLayout` with `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent`. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)
But for `PercentageLayout` we can use

```
 app:layout_heightPercent="33.4%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="45%"
```

Comment: when documentation says then why not use Constraint Layout ?

Comment: I want to use width and height as percentage

Comment: @Ameer Have created a sample using CoordinatorLayout which uses percentage for width and height. Hoping it helps https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-percent-layout-sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There're two ways to implement your layout with `ConstraintLayout`.

### #1 Guidelines

Considering you need to lay out six views you need to add two vertical guidelines with percentage position **33%** and **66%** of parent width. And you also need to add two horizontal guidelines with percentage position **45%** and **90%** of screen height. Then constrain your six views to those guidelines as shown on this screenshot:

[image: Layout Editor]

Here's XML source code for layout build with guidelines:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_guideline_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_guideline_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### #2 Chains with weight

Chains is another powerful way to achieve sizing your views with percentage values. You use weight value in ConstraintLayout chain like you use weight in LinearLayout.

Here's XML example showing how to use chains with weight:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="33.3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="45"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view4" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="33.3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="33.3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="33.3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="45"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="33.3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view4" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="33.3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view5" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Both of examples shown above lead to this result:

[image: Result view]

Read more about:

- [Guidelines](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7#4511)
- [Chains](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7#5c25)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the alternative for PercentageLayout

Use `ConstraintLayout`, as indicated in your question.

With the now-current production release of `ConstraintLayout` (`1.0.2`), set up a guideline at the desired percent location and constrain your widgets to the guideline.

With the upcoming `1.1.x` series (now `1.1.0-beta4`), you can use `layout_constraintWidth_percent` and `layout_constraintHeight_percent` on any axis for which you set the size to `0dp` (a.k.a., `MATCH_CONSTRAINT`).